# Push Android project to existing private GitHub repository

Tags: android-studio, github

I have a project, which I would like to push into a private `GitHub` repository, where I am a contributor. I tried to set VCS in `Android Studio`, Git is enabled, commit is done, but I cannot push it. Share on `GitHub` option isn't good for this purpose, because it offer to create a new repository with name of project. I couldn't found any option on this IDE to push to an existing private repository, because I cannot found list of repositories, where I have some roles(owner or collaborator). As I see I can set a specified repository only when I import it from git.

Comment: You must set `remote url` to your project so you can push it

Comment: @hrskrs . Where can I set this please?

Comment: what does `git remote -v` gives you on the command line?

Comment: You can set it from `Terminal` in `AndroidStudio` as: `git remote add origin git@github.com:YourRepo.git`